# Handling multiple AcquireTokenInteractive calls and preventing multiple browser login requests (MSAL)

Tags: xamarin, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

We have a number of calls that all require a Token from MSAL. These calls happen in parallel and look like this.

```
AuthenticationResult result = await this.pca.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();

headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

We are handling all the necessary MSAL exceptions such as MsalUiRequiredException – I have just removed those pieces for the sake of shortening the question.

In the situation where a RefreshToken has expired, we are faced with having multiple parallel calls causing multiple MsalUiRequiredExceptions to be thrown, resulting in our code calling `AcquireTokenInteractive` multiple times.

This means the user ends up with a stack of browser logins to deal with. How are others handling multiple unrelated calls needing an interactive login and therefore throwing up a browser?

Answer (score 0):

We are now using a **SemaphoreSlim** to control access to the code that tries to acquire a token.

After some conversation in the comment thread of the question I did look at using a `lock` statement but that is not considered a good idea when wrapping async calls. This is because of potential deadlocks and the possibility of different threads on the return of the await trying to release a lock they do not have access to.

Code now looks like this

```
await this.semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

try
{
    var account = await this.GetCurrentAccount();
    AuthenticationResult result = await this.pca.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
    return new AuthenticationResultWrapper(result);
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    try
    {
        // Acquire token interactively
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await this.pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(this.uiParent)
                                                        .ExecuteAsync();

        return new AuthenticationResultWrapper(authResult);
    }
    catch (MsalServiceException client) when (client.Message.Contains(BreathRmCloudDataSyncService.MsalForgottenPasswordErrorMessageCode))
    {
        // User selected forgotten password flow
        IAuthenticationResult authResult = await this.HandleClinicalServiceHandleForgottenPasswordAsync();
        return authResult;
    }
    catch (MsalException msalException) when (BreathRmCloudDataSyncService.ExceptionIsMsalCancellation(msalException))
    {
        // Nothing to do here, user cancelled the flow
        this.logger.LogInteraction("User cancelled authentication during interactive token acquirement.");
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        this.logger.LogException(exc, "AcquireTokenInternalAsync Try Interactively Failed: Unknown Exception: " + exc.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    this.logger.LogException(e, "ClinicalService - AcquireTokenAsync");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    this.semaphoreSlim.Release();
}
```